# Re-evaluate data types in Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this question is duplicate!!

I have a Dataframe like

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0                   
1   33  40  75  73  45
2   46  59  40  53  17
3   43  63  5   38  83
4   97  43  14  39  82
```

The cells of the first row are all empty strings `""`.

Apparently the dtypes are all object

```
df.dtypes
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
4    object
dtype: object
```

I generate a new Dataframe from the first using the code `df2 = df.iloc[1:,:]`.

df2

```
   0    1   2   3   4
1   33  40  75  73  45
2   46  59  40  53  17
3   43  63  5   38  83
4   97  43  14  39  82
```

The dtypes of this new df2 are still object

How I can re-evaluate the dtypes of the new Dataframe?

Clarification. suppose I have a dataframe in which each column has homogenous (int, float, and datetime) data except for a few rows which contain strings. If I delete these rows then how I make pandas re-evaluate the data types of each column. Should I simply save the dataframe and then read it again!

Comment: `df2 = df.iloc[1:,:].astype(float)`?

Comment: but they are not floats and I want to assign each row separately but data type might change

Comment: what are they? remember that `dtypes` returns `'object'` for mixed types, list, string, sets, etc...

Comment: This question is unclear to me ...

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti if you "assign each row separately " you will always get `object`, as stated by @QuangHoang

Comment: @WeNYoBen could you please let me know what is unclear!

Comment: Assuming you *know* you have numeric data, but aren't entirely sure what the safest type to pick is, you would do `df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')`.

Comment: Though I think this is an XY problem. Given your example, you could get around this problem by reading the file twice. First read only the header row to get the columns. Then read the file again this time skipping the header and unecessary blank row. (specifying skiprows). Now `pandas` will properly parse the data with the correct type and you can assign the columns using your first read.

Comment: Thanks, @ALollz, this is somewhat the route I selected. However, this is just a simple example. My appreciations.

Answer (score 2):

To re-evaluate the types of the columns after you modified the dataframe, try relying on df.infer_objects().dtypes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean change the datatype? if so try:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

you can replace int to float64 as well I believe

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could simply set the dataframe as int.

i.e.:

```
df2.astype('int')
```